# ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

I have a `Burson Audio Playmate Vivid` DAC. Recently it randomly stops playing and I get a bunch of messages in the `journalctl`. To make it work again I have to turn it off and on again.

```
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 12
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: USB disconnect, device number 13
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 000000043f6568c0 trb-start 000000043f6568d0 trb-end 000000043f6568d0 seg-st>
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 000000043f6568d0 trb-start 000000043f6568e0 trb-end 000000043f6568e0 seg-st>
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 000000043f6568e0 trb-start 000000043f6568f0 trb-end 000000043f6568f0 seg-st>
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: cannot submit urb (err = -19)
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: USB disconnect, device number 14
Nov 29 22:09:55 demonhost pulseaudio[963]: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP and XRUN: Input/output error
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=85.36
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: hub 1-5:1.0: USB hub found
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: hub 1-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost upowerd[1691]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0134, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: Product: USB PnP Audio Device
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.1: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152a, idProduct=86ed, bcdDevice= 6.f2
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: Product: BursonAudio USB Audio 2.0
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: Manufacturer: XMOS
Nov 29 22:09:58 demonhost kernel: usb 1-5.2: 1:3 : unsupported format bits 0x100000000
```

What do these messages mean?

PS: I recently RMA it and got new motherboard for the Burson. Since then it works fine, just this messages pop up and I have to turn it off and on again.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: @user1928764 No, I ended up selling the DAC eventually (but not because of this bug).

Comment: Michal, Thank you.